# ERROR: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Tags: python, pip

I ran the following command: `!pip install turtle` in my Jupiter notebook.

I got the following error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
        command: 'C:\Users\aayyu\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aayyu
\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-uudhzft1\\turtle\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aayyu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-
install-uudhzft1\\turtle\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r
\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\aayyu\AppData\Loc
al\Temp\pip-install-uudhzft1\turtle\pip-egg-info'
             cwd: C:\Users\aayyu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uudhzft1\turtle\
        Complete output (6 lines):
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "C:\Users\aayyu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uudhzft1\turtle\setup.py", line 40
            except ValueError, ve:
                             ^
        SyntaxError: invalid syntax
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I did not understand what went wrong. Please help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpip%5d%20turtle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
except ValueError, ve:
```

Is the old syntax for catching an error and assigning it to a variable. It was replaced by:

```
except ValueError as ve:
```

This comma syntax is deprecated in later versions of python2, and is a syntax error in python3.

It looks like what you're installing is specific to python2.

The `turtle` package is part of the standard library in python3, so it would make sense that the version available in pypi was python2 only.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `import turtle` you can use it without `pip install` or maybe it is due to the pip version you are using.